# list files from https sever using R

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I have a problem when tried to list all files from this https server using R ([https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODIS-Aqua/Mapped/Monthly/4km/sst/][1])

After listing all filename, then I would like to download the last/newest file

Anybody can help me?

here a shortcode I have tried to use, but still not working

```
url<-'  https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODIS-Aqua/Mapped/Monthly/4km/sst/'
f1<-getURL(url, curl = curl)
download.file('https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A20021822002212.L3m_MO_SST_sst_4km.nc', destfile = desf[length(f2)], mode = "wb")
```

1]: https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODIS-Aqua/Mapped/Monthly/4km/sst/

Comment: I'm using getURL for a different climate data website ```https:/www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/nclimgrid-daily/access/grids/2024/``` and get this error: ```Error: object 'curl' not found```. It looks like ```curl``` should be replaced with some sort of object, maybe a curl handle? Thanks, @Eko Susilo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
library(httr)
library(XML)

df <- readHTMLTable(content(GET("https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODIS-Aqua/Mapped/Monthly/4km/sst"), "text"))[[1]]

download.file(paste0("https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/", 
    tail(df,1)$Filename), tail(df,1)$Filename, mode = "wb")
```

Comment: You're counting on the idea that people will upload files by order ;) I would use sort by `Last Modified` just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks it's work for me. I add additional argumen `mode = "wb"` so the result can be read using `ncdf4 package`